# Office 365, oauth2, where do I find Key+Secret?

Tags: azure, authentication, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm trying for the first time to get access to 365 using oauth2, for my Native Application.
I have registered my application in Azure AD.
The documentation says, "...In the Azure Management Portal, select your application and choose Configure in the top menu. Scroll down to keys."

But in (my) Azure Application, Configure properties, I only have Name, Client ID, URL and Logo, and the Permissions area - No "Keys" area.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Web Application And/OR Web API

As tou are looking for KEYS , You need to create your application in AD as Web Application or web API

[image]

then you can find the Key and secret.

[image]

### Native Client Application

If you're developing  a native client app, you don't need the keys because this auth flow doesn't require them.

So first of all you need to use **[ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD)** (**A**ctive **D**irectory **A**uthentication **L**ibrary) use the right version for your client program.

Then you should to reference your AD configuration for the App, note there are no KEYs required.

```cs
// Native client configuration in AzureAD
private string clientID = "3dfre985df0-b45640-443-a8e5-f4bd23e9d39f368";
private Uri redirectUri = new Uri("http://myUrl.webapi.client");
```

Then prepare AD authority URL and create the Auth Context.

```
private const string authority = "https://login.windows.net/cloudalloc.com";
private AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
```

That's all, after that you need to ask for access tokens depending on the resource you want to access.

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
    try
    {
        result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Never);
    }
    catch (AdalException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ErrorCode != "user_interaction_required")
        {
            // An unexpected error occurred.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

the `resource` could be a webapi or office 365 resource URI

Comment: Thanks JuanK, But I am developing a Native Client Application.
Is that why I don't see/get the key+secret properties?

Comment: I have added some information related to native application

Comment: Thank you again JuanK, for your great help.

Comment: @kimstahnke If this helps don't forget to mark it as answer. ;)

Comment: Do you by chance also know how to do the above from a language that does not support .NET? I am programming in TCL for this project, which poses a bit of a challenge for 365.

Comment: Not really, I'll require further investigation, but the logic remains the same because it is an oauth flow. Nevertheless I recommend you open another question for that.